# jquery background fill 100% screen, but cuts off the part of the image

Tags: jquery, css, background-image, fill

I have used the code below to fill the whole screen of the page. What I actually need is to have it fully filled in **height**, doesn't matter is it not fully filled in width.I just need to have the background picture centered in the middle of the page with 100% height of the page. there can be spaces on sides, I don't mind. Of course I need to have ratio kept. I was trying to modify the code but I'm not sure can I do it. I lost some time on this one and I believe it will be pretty easy for someone more experienced than me. Thank you for any thoughts in advance.
the code is here:

```
    <img src="http://test.tucado.com/4play/_images/cdj2000-start.jpg" id="bg" alt="">
    <a href="home.html"><div id="wheel-enter"><img src="http://test.tucado.com/4play/_images/empty.png" width="100" height="100" /></div></a>
```

css:

```
    body{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}


#bg { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; }
.bgwidth { width: 100%; }
.bgheight { height: 100%; }

#cdj2000 {
    position:fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width:700px;
    height:500px;
    margin-left: -350px; 
    margin-top: -250px; 
}

#wheel-enter {
    position:fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin-top: -50px; 
    margin-left: -50px; 
}


img{
    border:none;
}
```

and jquery:

```
$(window).load(function() {    

    var theWindow        = $(window),
        $bg              = $("#bg"),
        aspectRatio      = $bg.width() / $bg.height();

    function resizeBg() {

        if ( (theWindow.width() / theWindow.height()) < aspectRatio ) {
            $bg
                .removeClass()
                .addClass('bgheight');
        } else {
            $bg
                .removeClass()
                .addClass('bgwidth');
        }

    }

    theWindow.resize(function() {
        resizeBg();
    }).trigger("resize");

});
```

BTW. I had to put empty image as button, as for some reason  on div didn't work. weird thing. When I added border to this div, it started to work but action was only on border... which is weird. of course i didn't want a border as it suppose to look as a part of background to be clicked.

jsFiddle here:[>> jsFiddle <<](http://jsfiddle.net/58MPb/)

Thank you for any thoughts.

Comment: Please make a JSfiddle with the code, its gonna be easier for people to help you.

Comment: [link]http://jsfiddle.net/58MPb/

Comment: All I actually need is to make reduce the image height (and keep the ratio of course) when it's bigger than the screen size. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, the JSfiddle does not work, but here is the resulting code that works on a test page:

```
<style>
   body{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}


#bg { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 50%;}
.bgwidth { width: 100%; }
.bgheight { height: 100%;}

#cdj2000 {
    position:fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width:700px;
    height:500px;
    margin-left: -350px; 
    margin-top: -250px; 
}

#wheel-enter {
    position:fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin-top: -50px; 
    margin-left: -50px; 
}


img{
    border:none;
}
</style>
<img src="http://test.tucado.com/4play/_images/cdj2000-start.jpg" id="bg" alt="">
    <a href="home.html"><div id="wheel-enter"><img src="http://test.tucado.com/4play/_images/empty.png" width="100" height="100" /></div></a>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(window).load(function() {    

    var theWindow        = $(window),
        $bg              = $("#bg"),
        aspectRatio      = $bg.width() / $bg.height();

    function resizeBg() {
            $bg
                .removeClass()
                .addClass('bgheight').css('margin-left',$bg.width()/2*-1);
    }

    theWindow.resize(function() {
        resizeBg();
    });
    resizeBg();

});
</script>
```

You were testing on the aspectRatio of the window for no reason. Since you want 100% of the window height no matter what happens, so I removed this part. To center the picture, I am using the negative margin trick, position it at 50% of the page, so in middle. Then I apply a negative magin equal to half the width of the resized picture.

Comment: Great, that's what I was after. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this:

```
var theWindow = $(window)

function resizeBg() {
    $("#bg").css('width', $('html').outerWidth());
    $("#bg").css('height', $('html').outerHeight());
}

theWindow.resize(function() {
    resizeBg();
}).trigger("resize");
```

If you want to keep the aspect ratio, remove the line that changes the width.

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/58MPb/3/

Comment: That's almost there, just one thing - it is left aligned, but Salketer already fixed it. Thank you very much for your help and time. I will definitely write this down as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've fixed it: http://jsfiddle.net/jcolicchio/58MPb/4/

First off, I changed the first line of JS to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Because it didn't appear to be running your code at all. You also had a backwards inequality sign, flipped that around too:

```
if ( (theWindow.width() / theWindow.height()) > aspectRatio ) {
```

The other solution posted here is much cleaner code, but kind of jittery for me.

Comment: thanks. but unfortunately, if the window height is bigger than the picture it goes up and leaves the empty space below, so it doesn't actually covers the 100% of height of the screen, if you know what I mean. but thank you anyway for your effort